# MVC Grid Delete Record Action Performing Full Page Load, How to stop this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

I have an mvc grid.

Next to each record is a delete button.

This delete button corresponds to an action DeleteRecord.  The action deletes this record and performs a RedirectToAction("MyGrid");.

This works pretty well but what is annoying is the fact that my redirectaction causes the entire page to reload.  This is something I am trying to stay away from, but can't seem to figure out a way around this.

I start out like this.

```
/MyApp/MyGrid  => click delete
/MyApp/DeleteRecord => redirect
/MyApp/MyGrid => full reload of page
```

Maybe this isn't possible but I tried doing this by using overriden actions and actions with different action names, but this didn't solve my full reload.  I am new to MVC so maybe this isn't even possible.  I was thinking maybe if I just did an ajax.post on the clientside that I could get away from this but the more I think about it the more likely that it just will end up in the same action performing the same redirect.

Any ideas on how to get around this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up just tying into the callback function of the grid and the inline delete of the grid function and it worked.  Although, extremely hackish, it stops the full post back by hoping into the inline grid delete code.  Although, you can't count on the callback javascript routines to run in order as that is just how javascript works right. ; o

```
s.SettingsEditing.DeleteRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "DeleteRecordGrid" };

s.ClientSideEvents.EndCallback = "function(s,e) { OnEndCallback(s, e, 'delete') }";

<script type="text/javascript">

    function deleteWithoutPostback(eVisibleIndex) {
        var okToDelete = confirm("Do you really want to delete this record?");
        if (okToDelete == true) {
            myGrid.DeleteRow(eVisibleIndex);
            myGrid.ClearFilter();
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

    function OnEndCallback(s, e, callType) {
        if (typeof callType == 'undefined') {
            if (callType == 'delete') {
                myGrid.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```